# Compilation Error

Tags: arduino-uno, compile

Hi everyone I seem to have run into a problem while uploading a library to the board. I managed to import the library to Arduino Uno, however, i could not upload it

Please Help :)

Thanks in Advance

This is the error i received:

```
Arduino: 1.6.11 Hourly Build 2016/08/05 02:12 (Mac OS X), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

In file included from /Users/pendukenipandeni/Documents/Arduino/SimpleTimer/SimpleTimer.ino:1:0:
/Users/pendukenipandeni/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SimpleTimer-master/SimpleTimer.h:37:22: fatal error: functional: No such file or directory
 #include <functional>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: Where did you get that library?

Comment: I got the library from gitHub : https://github.com/schinken/SimpleTimer

Comment: Looks like that uses `std::function` which is not in the normal Arduino compiler (by the looks of things) - or not in the version I have anyway. Maybe you need a specific installation for it to work. Simplest option is to pick one of the many other implementations of SimpleTimer out there.

Comment: Thank you Majenko, i picked another Simple Timer and it works now

Comment: please help, #include <IRremote.h> ^ compilation terminated. exit status 1 Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix this by simply downloading and uploading a different SimpleTimer Library from https://github.com/jfturcot/SimpleTimer